# C2143 with nested template classes

Tags: c++, templates, nested-class

Hi I am having some doubts regrading templates.
Please look into follwoing snippet.

```
template<class T_Type1>
class CSmall
{
public:  
  class Const_Itr
  {
    T_Type1  Outer_A;
  };
private:
  T_Type1  Inner_A;
};

template<class T_Type>
class CBig
{
public:
  CSmall<T_Type>::Const_Itr*            obj1;//ERROR C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
  typename CSmall<T_Type>::Const_Itr*   obj2;// NO error after using 'typename' keyword
}; // CIPPortExpectationHandler

void main()
{
  CSmall<int>::Const_Itr*   obj3;// NO error even if 'typename' keyword in NOT used.
}
```

can somebody explain me following

1. Why declaration of 'obj1' is giving error.
2. How typename solves this problem while declaring 'obj2'. what info is gained by compiler
3. Why declaration of 'obj3' inside main() works without typename.

Note: snippet is complied on VC++ 8.0

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

compiler has no clue if  `CSmall<T_Type>::Const_Itr` is a type or a variable. So you should provide some help. While `CSmall<int>::Const_Itr` is obviously a type.

Answer (score 3):

See this FAQ: [What is the template `typename` keyword used for?](http://www.comeaucomputing.com/techtalk/templates/#typename)